# Utilizing Node.js for Server-Side Rendering for API Services in WordPress blogposts

Tags: javascript

I have a WP blog where each post requires a unique JS code from the server side (SSR).

How can I do this?

I tried creating new NodeJS on Cpanel option:-

But I'm getting 404 when requesting the Server side JS.

Is this method really possible?

which of these 2 options will work?

WordPress Plugin: You could write a custom WordPress plugin in PHP that provides the server-side logic for your tool. This would integrate directly with WordPress without the need for Express or CORS. The plugin would use WordPress's built-in functions to handle HTTP requests and responses.

Separate Node.js Service: If you prefer to write your server-side logic in JavaScript using Node.js, you would set up a separate Node.js service using Express and possibly CORS. This service would run independently of WordPress, and you would call it from your WordPress site using JavaScript (AJAX or Fetch API). In this case, you would indeed use Express to create the server and CORS to handle cross-origin requests if your Node.js service is on a different domain or subdomain than your main WordPress site.